# How does one filter articles by category when using newspaper?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to use the Newspaper library for a simple news scraper.
http://newspaper.readthedocs.org/

After getting the article list like so:

```
cnn_paper = newspaper.build('http://cnn.com')
```

I'd like to get only the articles from a specific category. And while I can see the available categories, I can't find a way to filter the articles I have by the categories they have been downloaded from.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want retrieve articles for given category, then I guess  it should be something something like this (sorry if I got you wrong):

```
import newspaper

cnn_paper = newspaper.build('http://cnn.com')

for category in cnn_paper.category_urls():
    cat_paper = newspaper.build(category)
    print cat_paper.articles #Gives all articles of category
    for article in cat_paper.articles:
        print article.url #prints URL for all articles in given category
```

Comment: Got it. You need to rebuild the index by the category